# R XLSX java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

Tags: java, r, garbage-collection, out-of-memory

I wrote this r function that uses the `xlsx` package to write one or more data frames out to a .xlsx file. When given the same input (3 data frames: 6185 obs of 23 variables, 4 of 17 and 2 of 3) it throws an error *most* of the time, but not *all* of the time.

Can anyone tell me how to optimize my code, get the same outcome more elegantly or continue in spite of the error?

Here is the console output:

```
Running: WriteToFile()
WriteToFile:1
WriteToFile:4
Error in: Example Report
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceededReturning from: Example Report
```

and here is the function:

```
WriteToFile <- function() {
  # Write a data frame(s) out to .xlsx file

  if(debug > 2) {message("WriteToFile:1")}

  # If the file already exists today, then delete it
  if(file.exists(paste0(report.name, '(', today(), ')', ".xlsx"))) {
    if(debug > 2) {message("WriteToFile:2")}
    writeLines(paste0("File '", report.name, '(', today(), ')', ".xlsx", "' already exists and will be replaced."))
    flush.console()
    file.remove(paste0(report.name, '(', today(), ')', ".xlsx"))
  }

  # Get tab names that were generated in ProcessOutputs()
  tabs <- ls(pattern=paste0("\\.data$"), name=.GlobalEnv)

  # If no tabs, send fail-mail
  if(length(tabs) == 0) {
    if(debug > 2) {message("WriteToFile:3")}
    SendPerlMail(fail.mail=TRUE, fail.msg="No data for tabs in WriteToFile()")
    return(-1)
  } 

  # Write first tab to first sheet, then write any remaining tabs to additional sheets
  else {
    if(debug > 2) {message("WriteToFile:4")}
    write.xlsx2(x=get(tabs[1]), file=paste0(report.name, ' (', today(), ')', ".xlsx"), 
                sheetName=substr(x=tabs[1], start=0, stop=nchar(tabs[1])-5), col.names=TRUE, row.names=FALSE, append=FALSE)
    if(length(tabs) > 1) {
      if(debug > 2) {message("WriteToFile:5")}
      for(t in mget(tabs[2:length(tabs)])) {
        write.xlsx2(x=t, file=paste0(report.name, ' (', today(), ')', ".xlsx"), 
                    sheetName=substr(x=substitute(t), start=0, stop=nchar(t)-5), col.names=TRUE, row.names=FALSE, append=TRUE)
      }
    }
  }
  email.file <<- paste0(getwd(), "/", report.name, ' (', today(), ')', ".xlsx")
  return(1)
}
```

The outside variables referenced in the function are:

- `options(java.parameters = "-Xms2048m -Xmx4096m", "-XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit")` (I set these Java parameters because they worked for someone in another post with a the same GC error)
- `debug` = 3
- `report.name` = "Example Report"
- `Example Query 1.data` = data frame of 6185x23
- `Example Query 2.data` = data frame of 4x17
- `Example Query 3.data` = data frame of 2x3

Sometimes it outputs `WriteToFile:5` to the console and sometimes it succeeds without throwing the error. Any help is greatly appreciated--I've been trying to figure out why this doesn't work reliably for a few hours now.